Difference between columns,rows and lines in three dimensional spaces?
What's the difference between a line, a column and a row in three dimensional contexts? (I know that a column also means ''a supporting structure'' and that's not what this post is about).
Please, keep in mind that I am talking about three-dimensional contexts in the real world and not about two dimensional ones on a spreadsheet,seating chart,etc.
I know that column is vertical in two dimensional contexts (e.g. Excel)
There is a row/column/line of five buttons on the pants.
The kids in the classroom sit in four columns(row/lines.
They arranged the chairs in ten columns/rows/lines.
As far as I know a column is invariably vertical even in three dimensional spaces such as in classrooms, so if the Ls are students then this must be a column of students sitting in a classroom. (Again this is not a seating chart. Imagine being a teacher standing in the front of the classroom and looking down this column of students):
L
L
L
L
L
And a line is an umbrella term that can be vertical, diagonal and horizontal.
Also what's wrong with saying that, for example, the chairs have been arranged in vertical rows/lines or that the kids in the classroom sit in vertical rows/lines? By vertical, I don't mean they are stacked upon one another. What I mean is that they are BEHIND one another.
If a row is always horizontal so this must be a row of M:
M M M M M M M M M M
Kids in the classroom sit in columns? Again, I don't mean to say they are stacked upon one another. What I mean to convey is that they sit behind one another.
Also, row invariably means a line of people or things being NEXT TO one another and not behind one another as well, right?

When referring to seating arrangements it would be more common to refer to Rank and File  which removes the ambiguity of which you speak.

I assume that's British, though, right?

Not necessarily.  Ask any chess player or military person.

Most speakers of American English would speak of "rows of chairs" ; the average Joe doesn't speak of columns on the horizontal plane, except perhaps in military contexts.

Even if the chairs are BEHIND ONE ANOTHER and NOT NEXT TO EACH OTHER? (I am using the capitalized letters for emphasis and not to be rude. I don't know how to write in bold here.)

We need to know your context.  A speaker on a podium might take a question from the audience:  "You, in the third row, in the red shirt".  Not "You, in the third row, column six".

I'm British, but from what I can find in dictionaries file can mean 'a line of people one behind the other' in American English too.

I have already given you context. I can't give you any more. Can you please stop overcomplicating things and just tell me ?

bolded words are placed inside doubled asterisks. asteriskasteriskword word word word wordasteriskasterisk   No spaces between asterisks or asterisk-pair and the word it abuts.

You haven't given the speech context.  In what real-world situation do you want to make this utterance? Are you writing an architectural description of an auditorium? Are you talking to someone in the audience? What?  Did you read and understand my comment where I use the phrase "in the red shirt"?

"row invariably means a line of people or things being NEXT TO one another and not behind one another as well, right?".     Wrong.  Rows are in front of the row(s) behind  them and behind the row(s) in front of them.

So is it just row then? The seats or kids behind one another form a row then? Same with ducklings following their mother in a row?

It depends on your context, much as you resist that idea.  If you said "A column of ducks" it would be using column correctly but in an unusual manner.

I would call them the students in the next row. Lose the attitude.

Yes, as I said, rows are behind or in front of other rows.

No!! That's not what I meant. I am talking about the students and the ducklings BEHIND ONE ANOTHER.

They are the items "in" the row.   In an auditorium row, the chairs are beside each other but the row is in front of or behind another row.

Let's say the A's are students sitting behind one another or ducklings following their mother behind one another

Your question is all over the place. I have no clear idea what you wish to say. What kind of statement you are trying to construct.

A                                                                                                                                                  A                                                                                                                                                  A                                                                                                                                               A                                     Let's say the A's are students or ducklings behind one another. What do you call this line? A vertical row?

We call it "ducks in a row". Or a queue or a line if they are waiting for their turn. Thee's a line of people coming out the front door and extending all the way down the block.

What about the students who sit behind one another and not next to each other?

We do not typically, in everyday conversation, have a word for that.   "I sit in the third row" is normal.  "I sit in the third row and in   _______" is not something that comes out of any student's mouth in the US, except if the blank says something like "in from the door" or "away from the windows".  I sit in the third row, two in from the windows. or "You, in the tenth row, two in from the aisle."

This is still not the answer but never mind. According to dictionaries rows are always a line of things NEXT TO EACH OTHER and I am looking for the name of a line of things that are BEHIND ONE ANOTHER.

We might say "two chairs in from the windows" or "two seats in from the windows" or "two desks in from the windows" but most often it would simply be "two in from the windows", no noun at all!

And we use the version with no noun at all most often because there is no everyday word for the physical arrangement that is perpendicular to row

rows are always a line of things NEXT TO EACH OTHER Next means immediately adjacent; it doesn't necessarily mean side by side. (Also "line" in the US is more commonly called a "queue" in the UK, so you see why you need to tell us the context even if it's just where in the world you are.)

In American English, we might say:

I sit in the third row, two in from the windows.

No noun at all there.  Sometimes "two seats | desks in from the windows". But most often no noun because there is no everyday AmE word for the physical arrangement that is perpendicular (more-or-less) to row.
We don't say "I sit in the third row, two columns | files in from the windows."  Those terms are not everyday terms. They might fit your context, but we don't know what that specific context is.
Row numbers are from the vantage point of the front of the room.  File numbers would have to choose left or right orientation, which is even more arbitrary than front/rear. That might explain the absence of this word in everyday contexts.

This is the same in the UK. There is no difference between the US/UK usage here as far as I can tell.  Seating plans in venues are often not in perfect grid patterns, seats can even be staggered or rows can have different numbers of seats. There are often spaces where no seats can be placed - such as stairs/stairwells, structural columns, wheelchair access spaces etc, the room may not even be square, seating can be in different patterns to conform to the room, multiple aisles, etc, etc.

I don't understand why you seem to often say AmE when there's no justification for it. It's as Billy Kerr says.

@Lambie  You've asked me this before. I told you then that there are times when I  suspect  BrE could be different, and so I qualify my answer as coming from my experience as a speaker of AmE. This was one of those times. OP was asking about  lines, among other things, and since we say in AmE "standing in line" and they say "standing in queue" in BrE, I thought BrE might have a word for what the OP was looking for. I just didn't want to assume. I'm happy to take firm opinions when I feel myself standing on terra firma.

In my Canadian classrooms, the "L" lines of students were called "rows". The teacher would say things like:

Row three, you're too noisy.

There was no word for the "M" lines of students, and desks didn't necessarily line up across the room anyway.
I see from the comments that this might not be normal across the English-speaking world, so bear that in mind.
NOTE: In any other context, like in an auditorium or theatre, "row" indicates "M" lines of chairs, where the first row is the one closest to the front, the second row the one behind the first row, etc., and the back row was closest to the exits.

But when you talk about rows, do the students sit NEXT TO ONE ANOTHER or BEHIND ONE ANOTHER? Again I am looking for the name of the row where students sit BEHIND ONE ANOTHER. Row implies NEXT TO ONE ANOTHER.

@W55 By "L" lines I mean BEHIND ONE ANOTHER and by "M" lines I mean NEXT TO ONE ANOTHER, like in the diagrams in your question.
